# Hide the parameters passed through href tag

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am passing parameters through `href` tag as below:

```
<a href='message.php?toid=$userid&name1=$fname&name2=$lname'>
```

When I get redirected to `message.php`, the three parameters are visible on address bar. How can I hide these parameters? I came across `.htaccess` as one of the solution but without `.htaccess` I would like to hide the parameters

Comment: could consider POST, but that not really hiding much

Comment: But it's not possible to do a POST using a `<a>` .

Comment: Using jQuery you can delegate a click on a link and post to any page.

Comment: What is the point though? cosmetics?  I'd not rely on any method for security...

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you cannot hide the parameters that are sent through the `<a>` anchors tags.

However, you can obfuscate the parameters by encrypting them and then decrypting them on your server-side script.

#### A simple illustration using an encryption decryption ...

**`test1.php`**

```
<?php
$key_value = "somekey"; //<--- This is a key for the encryption decryption process
$plain_text = "the secret !"; //<-- The actual text you are going to send.
$encryptedmsg = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $plain_text, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT); //<-- Encrypting...
echo "<a href=test2.php?enc=$encryptedmsg>Click Here</a>"; //<-- Your anchor tag
```

**`test2.php`**

```
<?php
$key_value = "somekey"; //<--- Note..the same key !
$decryptedmsg = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $_GET['enc'], MCRYPT_DECRYPT); //<-- Decrypting
echo $decryptedmsg; //<-- Prints "the secret"
```

When clicked the link.. the test2.php will get the `enc` parameter and then decrypt it using the code , however, users will not be able to read the plain text.. **the secret !**

This is how it looks on the addressbar when you click the link from **`test1.php`**...

```
http://localhost/ext1/test2.php?enc=%D4%1D%96F|C%8B%8C%D7%8AP%19=%13%F6%A1
```

**Warning** : The `mcrypt_ecb` is deprecated. I just used it for the illustration purposes to give you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Actually, unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you *can* do this with an `.htaccess`. Something like `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?toid=$1 [L]` should make `site.com/index.php?toid=2` into `site.com/toid/2`.

Comment: So instead of mcrypt_ecb can I use mcrypt_generic

Comment: @Bina, Exactly. you got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to submit POST data as well, something like the following example:

```
$('#post').click(function(e) { // we assigned our link the id "post"
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: { name: 'John Doe', address: 'Some address' },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
              // $(".success").html( data ); // Optionally display result from post page instead of redirecting
              $(".success").html('We made a post! Yeah, redirecting you somewhere!');
              var end = setTimeout(function() {
                      window.location.replace(url);
                      clearTimeout(end);
                  }, 200);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $('.success').html('Something went wrong!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this link on the top of your code in message.php file

```
<?php if($_GET['toid']) echo header("location:message.php"); ?>
```

Comment: But then you'll be stuck in an infinite loop. You need to check if `toid` is set as well as the others and then save them somewhere.

Comment: I edited your answer to include the isset. That's important as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of you doing this is if you have a form with hidden input fields and the  tag is your submit. Just set the action as post.